# Exclude documents from QuerySnapshot and Listview Builder (Flutter & Firebase)

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I got a collection of questions in Firebase. The Categories are stored in an array. Now I want to to hide specific questions, if the user chose to hide it (User ID is stored in another array called hidden). This is what I tried:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("question")
                .where('category', arrayContainsAny: [widget.cid])
                .where('hidden', '!=', '${user.uid}')
                // also tried where('hidden', isNotEqualTo: [user.uid]) 
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                        return QuestionList(
                          de_du: data['de_du'],
                          de_sie: data['de_sie'],
                          de_ich: data['de_ich'],
                          qid: data['id'],
                          en: data['en'],
                          id: data.id,
                          documentSnapshot: data,
                        );
                      },
                    );
            },
          ),
```

Any suggestions on how to get there?

Updated:

I tried to implement the transformation. I still get errors and do not get it to work. The errors I get: the first snapshot in transform is undefined. Expects an ) right after the first snapshot in transform. Also I get the info, that the user (provider of userid) is not used.

```
class _CategoryDetailState extends State<CategoryDetail> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          this.widget.titel,
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Gruppo'),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network(this.widget.image),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(this.widget.titel),
                  subtitle: Text(this.widget.description),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'Fragenübersicht:',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Caveat', fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("question")
                .where('category', arrayContainsAny: [widget.cid])
                .snapshots()
                .transform(snapshot => snapshot.docs.where(d => doc.data().hidden.contains(user.userid).toList())),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data![index];
                    return QuestionList(
                      de_du: data['de_du'],
                      de_sie: data['de_sie'],
                      de_ich: data['de_ich'],
                      qid: data['id'],
                      en: data['en'],
                      id: data.id,
                      documentSnapshot: data,
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude a single item from a [Firestore query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) with a condition. What you'd need is an `array-does-not-contain` condition, which doesn't exist.

So that means that you'll have to read the additional items from the database, and then exclude them from the stream with something like:

```
StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("question")
    .where('category', arrayContainsAny: [widget.cid])
    .where('hidden', '!=', '${user.uid}')
    .snapshots()
    .transform(snapshot => snapshot.docs.where(d => doc.data().hidden.contains(user.uid)).toList(),
```

You'll need to update the builder too to reflect that it now gets `List<DocumentSnapshot>` instead of `QuerySnapshot`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! As I am pretty new with this – I still don't get it to work..
I get using a list to get the excluding done, but i don't understand how it is working. 
If i got the following stream:

stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("question")
                .where('category', arrayContainsAny: [widget.cid])
                .where('hidden', arrayContainsAny: [user.uid])
                .snapshots(),

how does .transform() work in the way that List = (data from category-where) - (data from hidden-where)

Tried to find more online but no luck.

Comment: The `transform` call transforms the `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` that you get from Firestore to a `Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>` and filters the documents that don't match the UID with `doc.data().hidden.contains(user.uid)`.

Comment: I did not get it to work yet.. fixed other challenges first.. this one is the next one up on my list.. will try it one more time to get it done with your already provided help and will get back to you ;)

Comment: Hey Frank,
I tried to implement the transformation. I still get errors and do not get it to work. The errors I get: the first snapshot in transform is undefined. Expects an ) right after the first snapshot in transform. Also I get the info, that the user (provider of userid) is not used.